# programatically save an Image in HTML5/Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have a button to save an image in png format. the image can be from a URL , from the resources or comming from a web api

I am a beginner in the web development world . I know that any button action can be done like this :

```
<input type="button" value="Save image"       onclick="saveimage();" />
```

or like this ( I am not sure which one is a better implementation)

```
<button type="button" onclick="saveimage();">Save Image</button>
```

I don t know what to put in the Javascript header to be able to save the image in png . any clue ?

thanks!

Comment: You have a visual-studio-2012 tag... Is this ASPX by any chance?

Comment: Do you have some other input controls that user can provide image? Is it always in .png or you might need to convert it?

Comment: @Rhs this is not ASPX , it is HTML5 with Java script

Comment: @EvaldasDzimanavicius it will always be in a png format. When you say input control , what do you mean ?

Comment: @user1415780 you wrote:  the image can be from a URL , from the resources or comming from a web api. How user will input those?

Comment: @EvaldasDzimanavicius from a url I will load the image URL , from the resources I will load it in the resource folder , from a web api , I am still working on it ...

Comment: @user1415780 ok, but then are you displaying that image? And are you trying to save the file on the server or on the local machine?

Comment: yes I will be displaying that image (work in progress) . and I intend to save it on the local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that I am aware of is this one:

```
<script> 
function saveImageAs (imgOrURL) {
    if (typeof imgOrURL == 'object')
      imgOrURL = imgOrURL.src;
    window.win = open (imgOrURL);
    setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("SaveAs")', 500);
  }
</script>
<body>

  <A HREF="javascript: void 0"
     ONCLICK="saveImageAs(document.anImage); return false" >
  save image</A>
  <IMG NAME="anImage" SRC="../apache_pb2.gif">
</body>
```

But it works only in IE.
It would be different story if you would use server-side scripting (php, asp).
Then you could set response headers to force user to download a file (get Save As.. dialog)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback
I tried to apply this method but ,even in IE , I get an error : once I click on the button it opens a new window saying "the resource cannot be found" and then a save dialog opens asking to save an htm page that returns to the same error page.... any clue ?

Comment: Just tried on my local machine - opens an image in a new window (IE9 and FF18). If you have "resource not found error" double check your src provided for the image and saveImageAs for onclick event should get document.ImageName as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks , I had a typo somewhwere and it works as you describe it :)

to my understanding , to get a Save As dialog , I will need to use php or asp , is there a way to do this in javascript ?

Comment: I meant , saving it without having to open a new window

Comment: Not that I am aware of. To save without opening a new window you need to send a response with correct headers (set for file). JavaScript does not provide that kind of functionality.